# Referencing multiple files that are not a certain file type in a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I am working on a script that contains a line similar to

"command /path/to/directory/*example*"

If the directory contains files that are named 1example.txt, example.tmp, example.war it will run the command on all of them. I would like for the command to be run on all of them except for the .war.  Is there some way of doing this cleanly?  The "/path/to/directory/*example*" is a string that is passed through.

Comment: Using ! in the string results in an unexpected bash event

Comment: Did you set extglob?

Comment: I can't use extglob :(

Comment: Why are you accepting a string from a user that is allowed to contain a glob?  That's a very bad idea.  What happens when a user passes `/*/*/*/*/*/../../../../../*/*/*/*/*` and your machine crashes?  Why not just accept a directory name and a literal string to be accepted as a substring?

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`:

```
find ~/tmp/example -type f ! -name '*.war' -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: So long as there aren't any directories this is fine, otherwise it does a recursive search which was probably not wanted.  But it doesn't filter for `example` either.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a command?  Kind of like how "*" means any character is there a not this character?  Its going to be used as an input for a "sort" command